# Zend Framework 2, filter a value after validation in an InputFilter

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-filter, zend-inputfilter

In an InputFilter I have this code:

```
    $password = new Input('password');
    $password->setRequired(false)
             ->getValidatorChain()
             ->attach(new Validator\StringLength(6));

    $password->getFilterChain()
             ->attach($this->passwordHash);
```

The problem is that the filter is applying to the value before the validation, so the validator always returns true.

I was wondering if there is any way to do the filtering after the validation.

Answer (score 1):

`Zend\InputFilter\FileInput` class is one of the input types that does [validation before filtering](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html). You can see how they solved it in the source code and make your own `PasswordInput` class based on that solution.

As you can see [in the source code on line 64](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/FileInput.php#L64) there is an if clause that prevents the filters to run as long as `isValid` is `false` (the initial value). So the validators run first and then when the parent `InputFilter` after validation calls `getValue` again to get the value from `FileInput` it runs the filters.

Answer (score -1):

It seems odd to filter after validation as the input before validation could be edited by the filters. Like strip tags or trim the string. If you do use a filter like `\Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum()` you could let it remove the whitespaces. So see it as bad practice to filter after validating your input.

E.g., take those filters:

```
// Default settings, deny whitespace
$filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum();
echo $filter->filter("This is (my) content: 123");
// Returns "Thisismycontent123"

// First param in constructor is $allowWhiteSpace
$filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum(true);
echo $filter->filter("This is (my) content: 123");
// Returns "This is my content 123"
```

Notice that the begin value differs from the result. But you can filter after validation, but I guess you have to it by yourself. So you could add a method to your inputfilter or form which you call after validation. For example:

```
public function filterPassword() {
    $filter = new \Zend\I18n\Filter\Alnum(true);
    $inputs = $this->getInputs();
    $password = $filter->filter($inputs['password']);
    return $password;
}
```

In your controller you can do this for example:

```
public function ExampleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function sampleAction() {
        $form = new LoginForm();
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $inputFilter = $form->getInputFilter();
            $filterdPassword = $inputFilter->filterPassword();
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if filter is needed in order to upload a file to the cloud, but all validation must be performed before it?

Comment: @AlexeyKosov, filters and validations should be executed before saving any data, whether its a model or an upload. And I have no clue what you mean by: "filter is needed in order to upload". Can you explain that a little bit further? As far as I can tell you don't use the filter to upload, but only to modify either the filename or en- or decrypt. PS: OP is asking for a way to do filtering after his validation and I provided him with an approach, so I don't see why your comment is related. The other answer is talking about `fileInputs` and I'm not responding to that.